# Qt show modal dialog (.ui) on menu item click

Tags: c++, qt, modal-dialog

I want to make a simple 'About' modal dialog, called from Help->About application menu. I've created a modal dialog window with QT Creator (.ui file).

What code should be in menu 'About' slot?

Now I have this code, but it shows up a new modal dialog (not based on my about.ui):

```
void MainWindow::on_actionAbout_triggered()
{
    about = new QDialog(0,0);
    about->show();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to setup the dialog with the UI you from your `.ui` file. The Qt `uic` compiler generates a header file from your `.ui` file which you need to include in your code. Assumed that your `.ui` file is called `about.ui`, and the Dialog is named `About`, then `uic`creates the file `ui_about.h`, containing a class `Ui_About`. There are different approaches to setup your UI, at simplest you can do

```
#include "ui_about.h"

...

void MainWindow::on_actionAbout_triggered()
{
    about = new QDialog(0,0);

    Ui_About aboutUi;
    aboutUi.setupUi(about);

    about->show();
}
```

A better approach is to use inheritance, since it encapsulates your dialogs better, so that you can implement any functionality specific to the particular dialog within the sub class:

**AboutDialog.h:**

```
#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_about.h"

class AboutDialog : public QDialog, public Ui::About {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AboutDialog( QWidget * parent = 0);
};
```

**AboutDialog.cpp:**

```
AboutDialog::AboutDialog( QWidget * parent) : QDialog(parent) {

    setupUi(this);

    // perform additional setup here ...
}
```

**Usage:**

```
#include "AboutDialog.h"

...

void MainWindow::on_actionAbout_triggered() {
    about = new AboutDialog(this);
    about->show();
}
```

In any case, the important code is to call the `setupUi()` method.

**BTW:** Your dialog in the code above is non-modal. To show a modal dialog, either set the `windowModality` flag of your dialog to `Qt::ApplicationModal` or use `exec()` instead of `show()`.

Comment: Thank you, Andreas! Going the simplest way for the moment... The fact is that the ui_about.h was not created, and it is not preset now. So the project with the code you specified first, doesn't compile. Is there a way to create ui_about.h manually?..

Comment: You can manually create it with `uic about.ui -o ui_about.h`. But your build system should take care of it - make sure that `FORMS=about.ui` is included in your `.pro` file.

Comment: Do you have any strange entries in the .pro file? There was a similar issue some time ago with resource files not being created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380171/qmake-not-generating-binary-resource-files/12431570#12431570

Comment: no, everything is fine in my .pro: FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    about.ui

Comment: I created ui_about.h from command shell, but when compiling I still get errors: 'about' was not declared in this scope

Comment: In the first line of the slot:
    about = new QDialog(0,0);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18704/discussion-between-andreas-and-michael-zelensky)

Comment: After manual creating the ui_about.h (automatic creation is still another open issue), and after defining about in the first line of the slot: QDialog *about = new QDialog(0,0); all works now!

Comment: I managed to get a vtable error when implementing this solution. It turns out I had to run `qmake` on my project since qt creator occasionally forgets to: https://forum.qt.io/topic/11994/error-undefined-reference-to-vtable-for-myclass

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the future users I would like to mention that I have encountered link errors corrected with the @Trevor Hickey [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170770/unresolved-external-symbol-public-virtual-struct-qmetaobject-const-thiscal/27647049). Do not forget to add the _moc_ file in to the project.Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

For modal dialogs, you should use [`exec()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec) method of QDialogs.

```
about = new QDialog(0, 0);

// The method does not return until user closes it.
about->exec();

// In this point, the dialog is closed.
```

[Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html) say:

> The most common way to display a modal dialog is to call its `exec()` function. When the user closes the dialog, `exec()` will provide a useful return value.

---

Alternative way: You **don't** need a modal dialog. Let the dialog show modeless and connect its `accepted()` and `rejected()` signals to appropriate slots. Then you can put all your code in the *accept* slot instead of putting them right after `show()`. So, using this way, you wouldn't actually need a modal dialog.