# Qt Serializion custom class

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

what is wrong in my code !!!! i got the following error message:
unresolved external symbol.
any suggestions .. and what is the proper whay to inhert from QObject whit out getting you trying to access private member .

```
namespace BioQt {
     class Location : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Location(QObject *parent );

    };
    QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Location &obj);
    QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, Location &obj);

    }


    Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(BioQt::Location, Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE);

#endif
```

and this is my cpp file

```
namespace BioQt {

Location::Location(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{

}



QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &ds, const Location &obj) {
    for(int i=0; i<obj.metaObject()->propertyCount(); ++i) {
        if(obj.metaObject()->property(i).isStored(&obj)) {
            ds << obj.metaObject()->property(i).read(&obj);

        }
    }
    return ds;
}
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &ds, Location &obj) {
    QVariant var;
    for(int i=0; i<obj.metaObject()->propertyCount(); ++i) {
        if(obj.metaObject()->property(i).isStored(&obj)) {
            ds >> var;
            obj.metaObject()->property(i).write(&obj, var);
        }
    }
    return ds;
}

} // namespace BioQt
```

Comment: There are several things that appear wrong with this, but start by posting the exact error message.

Comment: mention one of the several wrongs :) where even when i pass o or null to parent i got the same error ...

Comment: Your stream declarations use a double ampersand, which is a universal reference in C++11 and doesn't match the definitions.  You declare the class as a primitive type, which it plainly is not.  You define the stream operator inside the `BioQt` namespace instead of fully qualifying the argument type.  Now post the exact error message.

Comment: this is the error message :Location.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall BioQt::Location::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@Location@BioQt@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)

Comment: declarations use a double ampersand : i correct the post there is no  double ampersand in my code copy past issues :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const \* \_\_thiscall Parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170770/unresolved-external-symbol-public-virtual-struct-qmetaobject-const-thiscal)

Comment: the proplem in Q_OBJECT but how to solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to compile with **Qt 5.4.0 vs2010 x86** with no errors. Back in days with Qt 4.7, i remember sthg similar, moving the body to the header file and using **inline** worked for me, as i remember.

Comment: it's okay the problem was solved by deleting debug dir