# log4cplus unresolved external symbol LNK2001

Tags: c++, logging, build, linker, log4cplus

I am trying to use log4cplus as a logger in my project.   I have download and compiled log4cplus in VS2013 both 'Debug_Unicode' and 'Release_Unicode' successfully (project compiles successfully in Release and Debug).

In my 'Project Properties->Configuration Properties' I have added:

1. 'log4cplus\include' to the 'C/C++->All Options->Additional Include Directories'
2. 'log4cplus\msvc10\Win32\obj.log4cplus.Release_Unicode' to the
   'Linker->All Options->Additional Library Directories'
3. 'log4cplusu.lib' in the 'Linker->All Options->Additional Dependencies'

I have also made sure that I am using the same Runtime Library, in my case Multi-threaded DLL (/MD),  in both the log4cplus project as well as in my own project.

**But when I try to build my project I am getting the following link errors:**

> ```
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class
> std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
> std::allocator<char> > & __cdecl
> log4cplus::detail::get_macro_body_oss(void)"
> (?get_macro_body_oss@detail@log4cplus@@YAAAV?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
> log4cplus::detail::macro_forced_log(class log4cplus::Logger const
> &,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
> std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *,int,char const *)"
> (?macro_forced_log@detail@log4cplus@@YAXABVLogger@2@HABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PBDH2@Z)
>
> fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
> ```

Comment: I just faced a similar issue with Qt where following link had a suitable solution for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170770/unresolved-external-symbol-public-virtual-struct-qmetaobject-const-thiscal , Of course, the Q_OBJECT hack won't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows UNICODE build is built with `TCHAR` etc. being defined as `wchar_t` etc. When not building with `UNICODE` defined as build with `TCHAR` defined as `char` etc.

Building one library with `UNICODE` defined and attempting to link it in a project where `UNICODE` is not defined will result in linker errors since there will be a mismatch in the definition of `TCHAR`; `char` vs. `wchar_t`.

To correct this, build all the required libraries and projects with a consistent definition of `UNICODE` (and `_UNICODE`).

This can be done with either;

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
```

Or in the project settings;

> Project Properties > General > Project Defaults > Character Set

Or on the command line;

```
/DUNICODE /D_UNICODE
```

The alternative is applicable as well, if UNICODE is not intended to be used, make sure the defines are not set, and/or the multi-character setting is used in the projects and consistently applied.

Do not forget to be consistent between the "Release" and "Debug" builds as well.

Comment: my log4cplus project has the 'Character Set' property to 'Use Unicode Character Set' in my Release_Unicode and Debug_Unicode configurations which are the configurations used to build my project. The link errors still appear.  Is there something I might be missing?

Comment: Are they set in all the projects? Somehow `UNICODE` is not being set in the project giving the linker error (or it is being unset). Given the definitions for `log4cplus::tostringstream& get_macro_body_oss()` and `typedef std::basic_ostringstream<tchar> tostringstream;`, `tchar` is dependent on `UNICODE`; `#if defined (UNICODE)\n typedef wchar_t tchar;`. It still looks like the logger library was built with `UNICODE` set and your project doesn't have it set.

Comment: Your right, my project was set to Multi-Character, this is because I am using Pantheios which is configured to Multi-Character.  I have changed the log4cplus project to settings to Multi-Character, compiled it successfully, updated my projects 'Additional Library Directories' and 'Additional Dependencies' in the Linker node, and now everything is compiling as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: I've added a note on the alternative (i.e. not using the UNICODE) to the answer.