# Using signals into a class which is inheriting from QObject

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, signals-slots

I'm asking if there is a way to use `signals` in a class which inherits from `QObject` like this:

mysuperclass.cpp

```
#include "mysuperclass.h"

MySuperclass::MySuperclass(quint16 port, QObject *parent) :
  QObject(parent), port(port)
{
  this->connected = false;
}
```

mysuperclass.h

```
#include <QAbstractSocket>

class MySuperclass: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MySuperclass(quint16 port = 0, QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
   //there is nothing here
public slots:
  virtual void newValue(){qDebug() << "newValue";}
  virtual void connectionEstablished(){qDebug() << "connectionEstablished";}
  virtual void disconnected(){qDebug() << "disconnected";}
protected:
  QAbstractSocket* networkSocket;
  quint16 port;
  bool connected;
};
```

mysubclass.cpp

```
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QHostAddress>

MySubClass::MySubClass(quint16 ServerPort, QObject *parent) : 
  MySuperClass(ServerPort, parent) 
{
  this->networkSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
  ...
  connect(this->networkSocket, SIGNAL(connected()),this,
    SLOT(connectionEstablished()));
  connect(this->networkSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,
    SLOT(disconnected()));
  connect(this->networkSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(newValue()));
}
```

mysubclass.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include "mysuperclass.h"

class MySubClass: public MySuperClass
{
 public:
   MySubClass(quint16 ServerPort, QObject* parent=0);

 public slots:
   void newValue();
   void connectionEstablished();
   void disconnected();
};
```

Comment: Your class inherits from itself... It's a bit unclear what you're asking: look at e.g. the widget hierarchy in Qt, lots of inheritance and signals/slots. Does that not answer your quesiton?

Comment: what happens if you try it ? (after fixing the "Luke, I am my own father"-problem ;)

Comment: sorry for the mistake, a fixed it :)

Answer (score 7):

You must include the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the derived class too (but *don't* derive from `QObject` again). The macro is only mandatory if the derived class declares signals or slots. For emitting parent's signals or connecting with parent's slots it is not necessary (it also means that it is not necessary to re-define already existing signals or slots).

From [Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT):

> The Q_OBJECT macro must appear in the private section of a class definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other services provided by Qt's meta-object system.

**Example**

```
class MySubClass : public MySuperClass {
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    MySubClass(quint16 ServerPort, QObject* parent=0);

  public slots:
    void newValue();
    void connectionEstablished();
    void disconnected();
};
```

On the other hand, if you want to connect to a slot in the parent class but implement it in a derived one, then you must make it virtual:

```
class MySuperclass : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  // ...
public slots:
  virtual void newValue(); // can be virtual pure also
};

class MySubClass : public MySuperClass {
public:
  virtual void newValue() override; // overrides parent's
}
```

Note that there is no need to use the `Q_OBJECT` macro nor to use the `slot:` label in the derived class. Slots are normal methods after all. Of course, you have to use it if you add new slots or signals.

Comment: Sorry! but what you suggeste doesn't work :/ here is what i get:
`warning: C4584: 'MySubClass': the basic class 'QObject'  is already a basic class of 'MySuperClass'`
and
`Error: C2385: ambiguous access to 'connect'`

Comment: May you please post a more complete code (update your question) of both classes as well as the `connect` line that is failing to compile?

Comment: Mmm... please, update your question with that code correctly formatted, it's quite difficult to read it in comments. Also, publish the code of the super and derived classes you mentioned.

Comment: sorry for the illegible code but i don't have another way :/

Comment: In the meanwhile, please take a look at the updated answer to see if the new additions regarding inheriting from `QObject` helps you.

Comment: Is there any slot in `MySuperclass` called `connect`?

Comment: not realy a `connect` slot but you can look at again my code i updated it

Comment: I've successfully compiled your example afer two changes: add the `Q_OBJECT` macro to `MySubClass` (or remove the `public slots:` line), and you have a typo: `MySuperclass` in some places and `MySuperClass` in other ones... may be you have two clases and it is confusing? Nevertheless, after those changes it compiled correctly. Anything else you are missing to publish? Is the failing line included (the one with the ambiguous `connect`)?

Comment: i have errors again:

=>`MySubClass.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: 
Unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall MySubClass::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@MySubClass@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)`

=>`MySubClass.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: 
Unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall MySubClass::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@MySubClass@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)`

=>`MySubClass.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: 
Unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall MySubClass::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)"`

Comment: @kamal, I think the problem is expanding out of the original question. Have you tried with a [mcve] and from there start expanding your code until your final project? The last error is usually related to missing moc files. Take a look at [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/moc.html). What compiler/IDE are you using? qmake and Visual Studio Qt plugins takes those steps for you.

Comment: Another option, but less probable given the samples you've published, is that `MySubClass` is _declared_ in a .cpp file instead of a .h one.

Comment: The core thing with the aforementioned error is that the linker is not able to find the definitions of methods created when the `Q_OBJECT` macro was included. May be you have to update your project (running qmake if used) or recompiling everything? There can be many causes.

Comment: After a short googling, found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14172787/1485885). Take a look at it.