# vcpkg + Qt + Cmake + Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt6, vcpkg

I am trying to install `Qt6` using `vcpkg`, and use it in a `Visual Studio 2019 CMake project`. I have tried linking other libraries (ex: `fmt`) and it worked. However, when I add `Qt` in the mix, **building succeeds, but running the executable fails**:

the popup shows:

```
Program ... QtCored.dll
...
This application failed to start because no Qt platform could be initialized
...
```

and the console says

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\Qt6\plugins\platforms"
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Environment variables: I set `VCPKG_ROOT` to `C:\vcpkg`, `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` to `C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\Qt6\plugins\platforms`, `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH` to `C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\Qt6\plugins\platforms`, added `C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\Qt6` and `C:\vcpkg` to the path.

I tried putting the exe in a separate folder, and running windeployqt.exe on it, but it fails as well...

```
windeployqt.exe C:\Users\broland\Desktop\NewFolder\HelloWorld.exe

Warning: Translations will not be available due to the following error.
Cannot open C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/translations/Qt6/catalogs.json
Unable to find dependent libraries of C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\bin\Qt6Widgetsd.dll :Cannot open 'C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/bin/Qt6Widgetsd.dll': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170770/unresolved-external-symbol-public-virtual-struct-qmetaobject-const-thiscal
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)  # so that mainwindow.h and mainwindow.cpp is seen

project (HelloWorld)

find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)

find_package(Qt6Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6Gui CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable (HelloWorld "helloworld.cpp" "helloworld.h" "mainwindow.cpp")
#add_executable (HelloWorld "mainwindow.cpp" "mainwindow.h" "mainwindow.cpp")

target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE fmt::fmt)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE Qt::Gui)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE Qt::Core)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE Qt::Widgets)
```

Been trying for days. Any suggestions?

Comment: What dlls are in `C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\Qt6\plugins\platforms`  ?  This could be a vcpkg bug.

Comment: For Qt5 my vcpkg platform plugins are in: `vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\plugins\platforms`

Comment: answering your first question, the folder contains `qdirect2d.dll`, `qminimal.dll`, `qoffscreen.dll`, `qwindows.dll`.

Comment: for installation I used `vcpkg install qtbase[core]`, `vcpkg install qtbase[gui]` and `vcpkg install qtbase[widgets]`, and it defaults to `x64-windows` (if this is relevant)

Comment: Those are the dlls I have: qdirect2d.dll, qminimal.dll, qoffscreen.dll, qwindows.dll. However in my application's bin folder those get copied into a platforms folder. So I have `bin\Release\platforms` with these files and `bin\Debug\platforms` with the debug versions: `qwindowsd.dll` My Release executables for my project are in `bin\Release` and my debug executables are in `bin\Debug`

Comment: Are you using the vcpkg toolchain file with CMake? I have the following at the start of my CMakeLists.txt see the link: [https://justpaste.it/elmqn](https://justpaste.it/elmqn)

Comment: I added the code you provided, but the result is the same. About the bin folder, my folder structure is different, I cannot find it. I started the project as a CMake Project from VS, maybe that is why. My executable is in `C:\Users\broland\source\repos\helloworld\out\build\x64-Debug`. Here I get some dll's copied, but not the ones we talked about earlier. I copied them manually here and there, but with no success. Thanks

Comment: In the meantime I managed to make `Qt6` work with CMake by installing it through the online installer, not vcpkg. You are right, there might be a vcpkg bug involved.

Comment: I wanted to test this but the main problem for me (besides time) is I would have to create a new vcpkg folder probably in a vhdx file. The reason is I can not modify the vcpkg for my production application.

Comment: It is alright, thank you for your time and effort. I will stick to the workaround for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of using vcpkg, I installed Qt through the online installer.

For anyone else struggling, I will leave this here. I followed parts of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiMplRfuFJc) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0h1lC3QHLHU&t=187s) tutorials.

Since I use Visual Studio, I downloaded the `MSVC 2019 64-bit` version. I set the environment variable `QTDIR` equal to the path where `msvc2019_64` folder lies. I added to the `Path` env. var. `%QTDIR%\lib` and `%QTDIR%\bin`. To check if I can link other `vcpkg` installed libraries, I got `OpenCV` (`vcpkg install opencv`). It seems to work. The path in `INCLUDE` is where I have the respective file, ip, ua and var are folders of my project containing source and header files.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project (OpenCBDependencyTest)

#some magic
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
#set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
INCLUDE(C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)  # so that vcpkg installed packages are seen


# find packages
find_package(Qt6Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6Widgets REQUIRED)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)


# include files
set(IP_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ip")
set(UA_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ua")
set(VAR_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/var")

include_directories(${IP_DIR})
include_directories(${UA_DIR})
include_directories(${VAR_DIR})

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
    "${IP_DIR}/*.cpp"
    "${IP_DIR}/*.h"
    "${UA_DIR}/*.cpp"
    "${UA_DIR}/*.h"
    "${VAR_DIR}/*.cpp"
    "${VAR_DIR}/*.h"
    "Main.cpp"
)
add_executable (OpenCBDependencyTest ${SOURCES})


# link libraries
target_link_libraries(OpenCBDependencyTest Qt::Core)
target_link_libraries(OpenCBDependencyTest Qt::Gui)
target_link_libraries(OpenCBDependencyTest Qt::Widgets)

target_link_libraries(OpenCBDependencyTest ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```